# How can i dismiss a modal view controller using the default animation instead of a custom dismiss transition animation

Tags: ios, swift

How can i dismiss a modal view controller using the default animation (by tapping on a button) that also has a custom dismiss transition animation using the pan gesture via transitioningDelegate,since if i call dismissViewController the transitioningDelegate functions will be called instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a view controller presented modally with a custom transition, you can set up your transitioning delegate to return `nil` from `interactionControllerForDismissal(using:)` and the default transition style will be used instead.